# How to make sure two pandas dataframes cover same dates only

Tags: python, pandas

I have created 2 pandas DataFrames with data pulled from Yahoo Finance, and I need to make sure they are the same length in so much that they both cover the same dates - and if one is shorter than the other, drop any excess data from the longer one.

```
start_date = '2005/01/01'
end_date = '2016/03/31'

o=data.DataReader('EWC', "yahoo", start=start_date,end=end_date)
g=data.DataReader('ARGT', "yahoo", start=start_date,end=end_date)
```

So say, for example that the 'g' DataFrame only contains data from 2012 onwards, but the 'o' DataFrame contains data all the way from the start date in 2005.

How do I compare the two and drop any excess information from the longer one, so that they both start on the same date in 2012?

I have looked at joining, merging, concatenating etc - but I dont want to actually combine the two DataFrames in any way, I just want to strip one so they are the same length and contain the same dates on their index. I can't seem to find any simple way to do this.

Could someone suggest a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you don't want to combine the dataframes, this will trim the top and bottom dates to match:

```
min_date = max(df.first_valid_index() for df in [o, g])
max_date = min(df.last_valid_index() for df in [o, g])

o = o[(o.index >= min_date) & (o.index <= max_date)]
g = g[(g.index >= min_date) & (g.index <= max_date)]
```

Comment: Brilliant - this did exactly what I needed with minimal effort!! Thanks very much. I'll have to look closely at this code snippet and try to understand what it's actually doing!

Comment: Let me know if you'd like me to explain anything.

Comment: Wouldn't this be slower than the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36376342/2137255) `intersection` solution?

Comment: I believe that solution was added after this answer was accepted and it is a good alternative.  The question is for the OP to decide, as the behavior is different if there are gaps in data.  This trims the top and bottom.  With `intersection` it will trim data in the middle if one observation is missing due to a bad datapoint, for example.  This may or may not be desired depending on intended use.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to take the `intersection` of the index values:

```
In [11]:
intersect = o.index.intersection(g.index)
intersect

Out[11]:
DatetimeIndex(['2011-03-03', '2011-03-04', '2011-03-07', '2011-03-08',
               '2011-03-09', '2011-03-10', '2011-03-11', '2011-03-14',
               '2011-03-15', '2011-03-16',
               ...
               '2016-03-17', '2016-03-18', '2016-03-21', '2016-03-22',
               '2016-03-23', '2016-03-24', '2016-03-28', '2016-03-29',
               '2016-03-30', '2016-03-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=1278, freq=None)
```

You can use the above to index `o`: `o.loc[intersect]` will return just the rows that are present in both `o` and `g`